# Tool to convert PDF file into separate HTML files?

Tags: pdf, tools, html

I'm looking for a tool that will convert the pages of a PDF file to HTML files. I just need the text and formatting - I don't care about images and other media.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) is probably what you're looking for.

Info about the package: [packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/pdftohtml](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/pdftohtml)

Comment: Perfect. Just tried it out and it works great.